# Dynamic arrays as section headers

Tags: iphone, arrays, tableview, exc-bad-access

I have a main array, that contains a whole bunch of dictionaries, what I want to do is to have all those dictionaries sorted according to their assigned tag. This is how a dictionary might look:

```
date = "2012-12-04 20:26:04 +0000";
name = H;
tag = "#J";
```

Heres how the main array looks:

```
MAIN_ARRAY 
   - dict1
   - dict2
   - dict3
```

I want to sort the main array like this:

```
MAIN_ARRAY
     - tag1
       - dict1
       - dict2
     - tag2
       - dict3
```

Heres my code:

```
-(NSArray *)returnTagContent {    
    NSArray *tags = [all valueForKey:@"tag"];
    NSMutableArray *adoptTags = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    for (NSString *tagQuery in tags) {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tag CONTAINS[cd] %@", tagQuery];
        NSArray *roughArray = [all filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
        NSArray *tagContent = [[NSSet setWithArray:roughArray] allObjects];
        [adoptTags addObject:tagContent];
    }
    return adoptTags;
}
```

It returns the array, but now I want to organize it into section headers. How should I go about this?

I also have another piece of code with problem for returning the section header titles:

```
-(NSString *)returnTitleForTags {
    NSString *uniqueTag = nil;
    for (NSArray *tagContent in allTags) {
        uniqueTag = [[[tagContent valueForKey:@"tag"] allObjects] lastObject];
    }
    return uniqueTag;
}
```

Problem? Well, I know it's because of `lastObject` but any other ideas to retrieve a `NSString` object of the array.

**UPDATE:** New code changes.

I update the array to display the sections when clicked by a button so like this:

```
isTagFilterOn=YES;
[self loadSectionsArray];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Heres the code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
if (isTagFilterOn==YES) {
    NSDictionary *dict = [[sectionsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [dict valueForKey:@"name"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dict valueForKey:@"date"];
}
else {
    NSString *object = all[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [object valueForKey:@"name"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [object valueForKey:@"tag"];
}
```

The rest

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if (isTagFilterOn==YES) {
        return [sectionsArray count];
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (isTagFilterOn==YES) {
        return [[sectionsArray objectAtIndex:section] count];
    }
    return all.count;
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (isTagFilterOn==YES) {
        NSDictionary *dict = [[sectionsArray objectAtIndex:section] objectAtIndex:0];
        return [dict objectForKey:@"tag"];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your task becomes easier if you remove duplicate "tags" before you create the array for the table view data source:

```
// All tags:
NSArray *tags = [mainArray valueForKey:@"tag"];
// Remove duplicates and sort:
tags = [[[NSSet setWithArray:tags] allObjects] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

// Build an "array of arrays (of dictionaries)" as data source:
sectionsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *tag in tags) {
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tag == %@", tag];
    NSArray *onesection = [mainArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
    [sectionsArray addObject:onesection];
}
```

For example, if the `mainArray` is

```
(
    { date = "2012-12-04 20:26:04 +0000"; name = H; tag = "#J"; },
    { date = "2013-12-04 20:26:04 +0000"; name = X; tag = "#J"; },
    { date = "2014-12-04 20:26:04 +0000"; name = Z; tag = "#L"; }
)
```

then `sectionsArray` will be

```
(
    (
        { date = "2012-12-04 20:26:04 +0000"; name = H; tag = "#J"; },
        { date = "2013-12-04 20:26:04 +0000"; name = X; tag = "#J"; }
    ),
    (
        { date = "2014-12-04 20:26:04 +0000"; name = Z; tag = "#L"; }
    )
)
```

and you can easily access each section and each row within a section:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [sectionsArray count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[sectionsArray objectAtIndex:section] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = ...;
    }
    NSDictionary *dict = [[sectionsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"date"];
    return cell;
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSDictionary *dict = [[sectionsArray objectAtIndex:section] objectAtIndex:0];
    return [dict objectForKey:@"tag"];
}
```

Comment: It throws an exception `EXC_BAD_ACESS` at `NSDictionary *dict = [[sectionsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Comment: @Ravin455: I checked my answer in a test project before posting it, and it worked for me. - Perhaps you can check the values of `sectionsArray` and `indexPath` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to locate the problem.

Comment: i added a `boolean` so like this `if (isTagFilterOn==YES) { // the code }` and then do `[self.tableview reloadData]`

Comment: Thanks! I will try to take a crack at it myself and post the solution if I find it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20644/discussion-between-martin-r-and-ravin455)